# Disable creating logback log file

Tags: java, logging, logback

Is it possible to disable creating logback log files?

When I set level to **root** or **logger** elements to **OFF**, it will not log but the file specified in appender is still created.

Is there an option to disable creating this file? (other than deleting the config xml file)

Even if no logger (or root) links to the appender, the log file from appender is still created.

Thank you.

===========================================================================
Edit. I'm attaching my config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<configuration debug="false">

  <variable name="LOG_LEVEL" value="${mylevel:-TRACE}" /> 

  <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>${clogdir}/mylog.log</file>
    <append>true</append>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
      <pattern>%d %p %t %c - %m%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
      <fileNamePattern>${clogdir}/mylog.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}</fileNamePattern>
    </rollingPolicy>
  </appender>  

  <root level="${LOG_LEVEL}">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
  </root>

  <appender name="log2" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>${clogdir}/log2.log</file>
    <append>true</append>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
      <pattern>%d %p %t %c - %m%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
      <fileNamePattern>${clogdir}/log2.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}</fileNamePattern>
    </rollingPolicy>
  </appender>

  <logger name="log2" level="TRACE">
   <appender-ref ref="log2" />
  </logger>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the file appender is declared in your configuration then Logback will create an instance of the appender class and invoke `start()` on it. You can see this in [`AppenderAction.end()`](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback/blob/4dd08e68321548cd85251ec389f5a832505e1268/logback-core/src/main/java/ch/qos/logback/core/joran/action/AppenderAction.java#L90). Calling `start()` on a `FileAppender` will cause the appender's configured file to be created, you can see this behaviour in [`FileAppender.start()`](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback/blob/4dd08e68321548cd85251ec389f5a832505e1268/logback-core/src/main/java/ch/qos/logback/core/FileAppender.java#L127).

So, in order to fully disable the file output appender you must ensure that it is not declared in your Logback configuration.

Perhaps you are looking for some way to mark your file output appender as a no-op i.e. no events to be emitted to it **and** no file to be created. There is no way - with Logback's current implementation (and subclasses) of `FileAppender` - to mark the appender as a complete no-op. To implement this you would need to provide your own subclass of `FileAppender` and override `start()`.

Comment: I have attached my log file. The root logger should be created only when I specify it. Now I can only tell it not to append log lines by setting LOG_LEVEL to OFF. But the file myLog.log is still created. Even if I change `<root level="${LOG_LEVEL}"> <appender-ref ref="FILE" /></root>` to `<root level="${LOG_LEVEL}"><appender-ref ref="NONEXISTANT" /></root>`. The log2 is created every time, that's ok.

Comment: Apologies, I have updated my answer, turns out that just including the appender in the config (regardless of whether that appender is even referenced by a logger) is enough to cause the appender's file to be created.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is it possible to reference other xml in the config? I'm thinking about the possibility to define the appender in other xml file and then reference it only when needed..

Comment: You could perhaps use [conditional configuration](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#conditional) to enable/disable your file appender. In this way you could have one logback.xml file but with two different behaviours depending on a condition such as the value of a JVM system parameter e.g. `-Denable.file.output=true|false`

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you very much :)